# What is the meaning of roots for $p(x)$ derived from the extension field $F[x]/p(x)$?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, field-theory, roots, extension-field

In my Analysis class, a section demonstrates how the extension field $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ provides a root for $x^2 + 1$.

In an example leading up to this formal definition for the complex numbers, [THIS EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxXZW.png) is given to familiarize the reader with the idea of an extension field providing a root to an irreducible polynomial $p(x)$.

While in the formal definition of imaginary numbers, $[x]$ is shown to be the $\sqrt{-1}$, in the attached example I can not make sense of $[x]$ as a root for $x^2 + x + 1$. In the formal definition of the complex numbers, the extension field $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + 1)$ represents the entire complex numbers. Does $K$ in the attached example represent just a portion of complex numbers? How can I determine $[x]$ in terms of complex numbers? What do I learn about $p(x)$ and its complex roots from what I have learned about its root in $K$?

I understand the theorems stating that field extensions contain a root of $p(x)$ but I do not understand how to determine what that root really is relative to $p(x)$.

Thank you!

Comment: The example you mention is an extension of the $2$-element field, not an extension of the field of real numbers.  You should check that this extension is a $4$-element field, and it would probably be useful for you to write out its addition and multiplication tables. It has nothing to do with the complex field (except for being obtained from some smaller field by adjoining a root of a quadratic equation), and, in particular, its elements are not complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you elaborate on what root [x] reveals about p(x) included in the example? What do we gain by creating a field extension where p([x])=0? Also, if [x] is not a complex number, is it a root in addition to the polynomial's two complex roots? Totaling to 3?

Comment: What do we gain? Immediately, we get the existence of a $4$-element field. We also get that the equation $x^2+x+1$ over the $2$-element field is solvable in an extension. In the longer term, applying the same method to other polynomials, we get lots of fields and we get that arbitrary non-constant polynomials over any field are solvable in suitable extension fields. So we can work with such solutions using the same algebraic identities that we learned for ordinary numbers.

Comment: Is it an additional root beyond the two complex roots? No, because the coefficients $1$ in the equation $x^2+x+1=0$ and the $0$ on the right side of the equation and the plus sign have different meanings depending on what field you're working in. In the example you cited, that field was the $2$-element field, whereas to get complex roots, that field would be the real numbers.